# Get Positive Bits Indexes from Bit Array

Tags: asp.net, arrays

Say I have the following BitArray combinedResults = searchBitArray.And(genreBitArray);

Which contains positive bits i.e 100100110000

How can I get the indexes of all the positive ones ?

Comment: How do you need to use the bit positions later?  Can you give an example of the type of result you'd like to see and what you would do with it given the provided array?

Comment: Basically I want to find all the indexes of the positive bits, as these provide the indexes to a search index I have (Lucene.NET). Basically then I want to display on the screen all the positive indexes as these are the search results

Comment: So what would you want back?  List<int>?

Comment: That would work an array then off all positive bits ye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a first, decidedly ghetto, crack at it:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(new bool[] {true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false});
List<int> pos = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
{
    if (ba[i])
        pos.Add(i);
}
```

That would give you a list containing 0, 3, 6, 7.  You could start at ba.Length - 1 and decrement down to zero if you need to read from right to left.

edit: Wrapped in an extension method, just because:

```
void Main()
{
    BitArray ba = new BitArray(new bool[] {true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false});

    List<int> positives = ba.GetBitPositions(true);
    List<int> negatives = ba.GetBitPositions(false);
}

public static class BitArrayExtensions
{
    public static List<int> GetBitPositions(this BitArray ba, bool MatchCondition)
    {
        List<int> pos = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ba[i] == MatchCondition)
                pos.Add(i);
        }

        return pos;
    }
}
```